# Struts2 s:/optiontransferselect one above the other instead of side by side

Tags: struts2

I'm a noob with struts.

I started to work on a Struts project and i want to know if it is possible to have the two lists (in an `<s:optiontransferselect />`) one above the other instead of side by side.

I need that so that the user can see the long name for values in the list, as there is a limited width that doesn't allow to see full name when they are side by side

Thank you =)

Comment: I would first look at the generated HTML and see if you can solve this via CSS; much of it likely can be. I would then not use the tag and role your own or use an existing JS solution.

Comment: The generated html is a table (one td for the choice list, one for the move buttons and one for the selected choices) there is no id on the table so I can't manage how it is displayed :(

Comment: Only if you're using the default theme. Personally I've never used the standard built-in pseudo-components because they're too opinionated and represent the state of the web when they were first developed. I encourage people not to the more-complex "components" at all. (Technically I used it once, but only because had to cover it for a book :p

Comment: What would you suggest me to do for this case ? I'm a beginner and it's a mess in my mind (sorry for my english). Thx for the help btw

Comment: I would suggest either duplicating `<s:optiontransferselect>` functionality yourself, or finding a component someone else has built that does the same thing. The S2 UI tags are... adequate at best, but limited in how you can work with them if they don't already do exactly what you want. You *may* be able to try using a different `theme` (https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/themes.html) for either just that component, or the site in general, to work around it.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i will try thoses suggestions !